# Which ball touches the ground first? Different explanations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, drag, free-fall

Two balls with the same shape and volume but very different masses are dropped from the same height WITH air.

The heavier ball should land first, but is it because of terminal velocity (see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127791/)) or because they accelerate differently (see [this other answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282716))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers are correct, however the balls don't ever reach terminal velocity if the height is too low. You could argue that an object with higher terminal velocity will also accelerate faster in the beginning, but that only boils down to the second answer with one extra step in between. So I would say the second answer (different acceleration) is better.

Comment: I found a [third answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46214/) that seems to agree